# where can i find SFMC BrandBuilder

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking for SFMC BrandBuilder in help document it says its under "email" --> "Admin" --> "BrandBuilder"
Link below.

In screenshot i cant see the option Brand Builder any idea how / where i can find this feature?

[SFMC BrandBuilder - MarketingCloud Help](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/imh_brandbuilder/)

[image: BrandBuilder]

Answer (score 1):

In documentation its clearly mentioned.
[Prerequisites](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/imh_brandbuilder/)

Prerequisites

Salesforce must enable this feature and create a brand for your account and for every business unit within an Enterprise 2.0 account. You must use an account enabled with permissions to view this feature for the link to appear. Contact your Marketing Cloud relationship manager to accomplish these tasks before following the directions in this document.

Comment: sorry about that...i did not see this part.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the oldest answer is now redirected to [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_brandbuilder.htm&type=5), where no prerequisites are mentioned.

At first, I also could not find BrandBuilder in the Setup, but it turned out that I was in the wrong business unit. When I switched to the parent business unit, BrandBuilder was present in the Setup.